# Getting "Having trouble finding non-duplicated centers" error when bigkmeans is called in R

Tags: r

I am trying to use `bigkmeans` with `big.matrix` (backed by a file) in R but I am getting a error:

> Having trouble finding non-duplicated centers

My matrix (42700x42700) is a dissimilarity matrix (lower triangle is filled) and its size is 13GB and centers parameter is given as 279.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. It was my fault that when I was loading big matrix as `read.big.matrix` function I had forgotten to give sep parameter and used default one (my file separator is not default comma ','). So it loaded only one row as I guess. And It caused that `bigkmeans` was having trouble finding 279 rows (randomly selected) that are different. Thank you Jay Emerson (one of the bigkmeans authors) for your helps.